# Problem with getting right return from function

Tags: python, function, return

why does my code return wrong ticket prices? I am supposed to add a time factor as well, but can't get even this to work. This is what I am supposed to do:

```
"""
Price of one bus ticket
time 6-17, price 2.7, age 16-64
time 18-22, price 3.5, age 16-64
time 23 and 0-5, price 4, age 16-64
for ages 0-2 ticket is free at all times
time 6-17, price 1.7, ages 3-15 and 65 -->
time 18-22, price 2.5, ages 3-15 and 65 -->
time 23 and 0-5, price 3.0, ages 3-15 and 65 -->
"""

def calculate_ticket_price(age):
    ticket_price = 0
    while True:
        if age >= 0 or age <= 2:
            ticket_price = 1.0
        if age <= 15 or age >= 3 or age >= 65:
            ticket_price = 1.5
        if age > 15 or age < 65:
            ticket_price = 2.7

        return float(ticket_price)


def main():
    age = 5
    price = calculate_ticket_price(age)
    print(price)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Had a little trouble posting the code, but the instructions should be in docstrings.

Comment: Just to clarify! Does your code report an error or returns the wrong price?

Comment: Returns wrong price. I had the time variable there as well in the beginning but it came out terrible so I thought I should figure this out first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’ll return the wrong price cause you’re using `or` where you need an `and`.

Your first if statement should be:

```
if ((age >= 0) and (age <= 2)):
```

Your second if statement should be:

```
if (((age <= 15) and (age >= 3)) or (age >= 65)):
```

Then your third one:

```
if ((age > 15) and (age < 65)):
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `or` when I think you want to be using `and`.  For example, this condition:

```
if age >= 0 or age <= 2:
```

is going to be true for any positive number, since the first part will always match.

You also want to be using `elif` so that only one of these blocks will happen.  Your last condition:

```
        if age > 15 or age < 65:
            ticket_price = 2.7
```

is going to happen any time the age is under 65 `or` over 15 (which is going to be every number), so I'd expect that your function just always returns 2.7.

A simpler way to write this function that follows the simple age-only rules you're trying to implement would be:

```
def calculate_ticket_price(age: int) -> float:
    if age <= 2:
        return 0.0  # infant price
    elif age <= 15:
        return 1.5  # youth price
    elif age <= 65:
        return 2.7  # adult price
    else:
        return 1.5  # senior price
```

In this very simple example, only the first condition that matches will `return` a value, so testing both sides of the range isn't necessary.

You can also check for an age to be within a particular range by writing an expression like `2 < age <= 15`, or `age > 2 and age < 15`, or even `age in range(2, 16)`.

Note that putting everything inside a `while` loop serves no purpose at all -- avoid having lines of code that don't do anything useful, since they're just one more place for bugs to appear.  :)

As far as having the function account for both age and time, I notice that the fare table amounts to giving youth/seniors the same $1 discount regardless of what time it is, so I might simplify it down like this rather than have a different condition for each age/time combination:

```
def calculate_ticket_price(time: int, age: int) -> float:
    # Infants ride free
    if age <= 2:
        return 0.0
    # Youth and seniors get a $1.00 discount
    discount = 1.0 if age <= 15 or age >= 65 else 0.0
    if 6 <= time <= 17:
        return 2.7 - discount
    if 18 <= time <= 22:
        return 3.5 - discount
    if 0 <= time <= 5 or time == 23:
        return 4.0 - discount
    raise ValueError(f"invalid time {time}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calculate_ticket_price(age, time):
    while True:
        if time >= 6 or time <= 17 and age > 15 or age < 65:
            ticket_price = 2.7
        elif time >= 18 or time <= 22 and age > 15 or age < 65:
            ticket_price = 3.5
        elif time >= 23 or time >= 0 or time <= 5 and age > 15 or age < 65:
            ticket_price = 4.0
        elif time >= 6 or time <= 17 and age <= 15 or age >= 3 or age >= 65:
            ticket_price = 1.7
        elif time >= 18 or time <= 22 and age <= 15 or age >= 3 or age >= 65:
            ticket_price = 2.5
        elif time >= 23 or time >= 0 or time <= 5 and age <= 15 or age >= 3 or age >= 65:
            ticket_price = 3.0
        else:
            ticket_price = 0.0

        return float(ticket_price)


def main():
    age = 5
    time = 12
    price = calculate_ticket_price(age, time)
    print(price)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Made these edits. Should there be and between every >=, <= etc..?